# Dúvida MVC e JAVA

Tags: java, mvc, controller, view, model

Dando continuidade a um projeto da faculdade que estava parado, pretendo faze-lo em Java já fiz e refiz do zero umas 2 vezes porém, ficava horrível e a cada aula eu percebia que dava pra fazer melhor, então resolvi tentar em organizar o código usando MVC.

Minha dúvida é: Por que esse código não está funcionando? Já fazem uns três dias que estou nessa lendo o stackoverflow e até agora não encontrei o problema.

Estou usando como base esse tutorial:
http://www.gqferreira.com.br/artigos/ver/mvc-com-java-desktop-parte3

**Model**

```java
     package duvidamvc;

    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class DuvidaModel {
        // Construtor
        public DuvidaModel() {
            iniciar();
        }

        public void iniciar() {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Funcionou.");
        }
    } //aqui tinha uma chave sobrando
```

**Controller**

```java
   package duvidamvc;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class DuvidaController implements ActionListener {
    private DuvidaView view;
    private DuvidaModel modelo;

    // Construtor
    public DuvidaController(DuvidaView view) {
        this.view = view;
        this.view.getBtUm().addActionListener(this);
        this.view.getBtDois().addActionListener(this);
        this.view.getBtTres().addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == this.view.getBtUm()) {
            chamandoModel();
        }
        if (e.getSource() == this.view.getBtDois()) {
            chamandoModel();
        }
        if (e.getSource() == this.view.getBtTres()) {
            chamandoModel();
        }
    }

    private void chamandoModel() {

        modelo = new DuvidaModel();
        modelo.iniciar();
    }
}
```

**View**

```java
    package duvidamvc;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class DuvidaView extends JFrame {
        // Encapsulamento
        private JFrame tela;
        private JPanel painel;
        private JButton btUm;
        private JButton btDois;
        private JButton btTres;

        // Construtor
        public DuvidaView() {
            janela();
        }

        public JButton getBtUm() {
            return btUm;
        }

        public JButton getBtDois() {
            return btDois;
        }

        public JButton getBtTres() {
            return btTres;
        }

        public void janela() {
            JFrame tela = new JFrame();
            painel = new JPanel();
            // painel.setLayout(null);
            tela.setTitle("Duvida padrão MVC");
            tela.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            tela.add(painel);
            tela.setSize(400, 80);
            btUm = new JButton("Exemplo 1");
            painel.add(btUm);
            btDois = new JButton("Exemplo 2");
            painel.add(btDois);
            btTres = new JButton("Exemplo 3");
            painel.add(btTres);
            tela.setVisible(true);
            pack();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new DuvidaView();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Coloque quatro espaços antes de cada linha de código para formatá-la como código. Ou selecione o seu código e clique no botão com o {}.

Comment: James, qual o `error` que está sendo exibido no seu `IDE`?

Comment: A IDE não da absolutamente nenhum erro, esse é o problema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro, se você colocar um `JOptionPane` no seu model, você já está violando o MVC. Componentes swing são coisas da view. Não coloque absolutamente nada que referencie qualquer interface com o usuário no model.

Segundo, que você deveria ter só um model. Mas como você está instanciando o model dentro do método `chamandoModel` e esse mesmo método acaba largando o model para o coletor de lixo, mais uma vez você violou o MVC. O controller serve para colar a view na model e não para criar e recriar a model sempre que alguma ação for executada. O campo `private DuvidaModel modelo;` que é o que você provavelmente deveria usar, você não está usando.

Terceiro, que `DuvidaController implements ActionListener` é uma péssima prática de programação. Mais ainda que você joga o controle de todos os botões no mesmo método para depois separar com um monte de ifs, o que é outra má prática de programação. Dê um método para cada botão e não os misture.

Quarto, não viole o encapsulamento da view na controller. A view deve avisar a controller, e não a controller acessar os componentes da view para se injetar lá.

Quinto, ou você usa `extends JFrame` ou então você cria o `JFrame` com `new`. Os dois juntos não faz sentido.

Assim sendo, o seu código pode ser isso daqui:

```
package duvidamvc;

public class DuvidaModel {

    public DuvidaModel() {
    }

    public String fazerAlgumaCoisa(int n) {
        return "Funcionou " + n + ".";
    }
}
```

```
package duvidamvc;

public class DuvidaController {
    private final DuvidaView view;
    private final DuvidaModel modelo;

    public DuvidaController(DuvidaModel modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.view = new DuvidaView(this);
    }

    public String clicouBotao1() {
        return modelo.fazerAlgumaCoisa(1);
    }

    public String clicouBotao2() {
        return modelo.fazerAlgumaCoisa(2);
    }

    public String clicouBotao3() {
        return modelo.fazerAlgumaCoisa(3);
    }
}
```

```
package duvidamvc;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DuvidaView {

    public DuvidaView(DuvidaController controller) {
        JFrame tela = new JFrame();
        painel = new JPanel();
        //painel.setLayout(null);
        tela.setTitle("Duvida padrão MVC");
        tela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tela.add(painel);
        tela.setSize(400, 80);

        btUm = new JButton("Exemplo 1");
        painel.add(btUm);
        btUm.addActionListener(e -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, controller.clicouBotao1()));

        btDois = new JButton("Exemplo 2");
        painel.add(btDois);
        btDois.addActionListener(e -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, controller.clicouBotao2()));

        btTres = new JButton("Exemplo 3");
        painel.add(btTres);
        btTres.addActionListener(e -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, controller.clicouBotao3()));

        tela.setVisible(true);
        tela.pack();
    }
}
```

```
package duvidamvc;

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DuvidaModel m = new DuvidaModel();
        new DuvidaController(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu estou tendo como base apenas o artigo do link abaixo, pois não encontrei nenhum livro ou nada que acrescentasse com exemplos práticos o uso do MVC com java, ao meu ver parece que cada desenvolvedor implementa da forma que acha correto, tanto que quando questionei isso em outra comunidade me falaram "MVC não é uma lei", então por esse comentário me deu a perceber que realmente cada um faz do jeito que bem entende tomando a ideia apenas do conceito que alguém jogou em algum lugar em algum momento na internet.

Comment: Poderiam me recomendar algum conteúdo sobre esse assunto com alguns exemplos ou algum projeto simples que me faça entender melhor o conceito?

Comment: @James https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: @James Não existe uma única forma, um único jeito de fazer MVC. O que existem são conceitos e princípios que devem ser respeitados e objetivos que devem ser atingidos.

Comment: @James O mais importante é separar o model do view. O model é o responsável por armazenar regras de negócio e não deve ser poluído com lógica de visualização. Se o seu model for feito corretamente, se você trocar o seu sistema swing para um em JSF, ou para JavaFX, ou para console, ou para webservice, ou para o que quer que seja, você não deverá/deveria mudar uma única vírgula do seu model. Por outro lado o view deve conter apenas e tão somente lógica de visualização e ser burro, deixando toda a inteligência do sistema apenas no model.

Comment: @James Depois que você separar o view do model adequadamente, fica faltando ainda alguma coisa para que um possa falar com o outro, e é aí que entra o controller.

Comment: Devo deixar os listeners na view ou no controller?

Comment: @James Preferenciamente na view.

Comment: então caso eu um dia mude meu sistema para JavaFX ou para console por exemplo, eu deveria mudar apenas o view e controller ou apenas o view?

Comment: @James Idealmente apenas a view, mas na maioria das vezes, acaba tendo que mudar também o controller, o que também está tudo bem. O problema é se tiver que mudar o model.